# count occurence in ranges in R

Tags: r, tapply

My dataset looks like this

```
 98      11
 99.5    12
 100     12
 101     13
 100.2   10
 100.5   10.5
```

I want to create a result set which looks like this

```
         10-11   11-12  12-13  
 98-99    1      1       0
 99-100   0      1       0
 100-101  2      1       1
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Look at `cut` and `table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boundary condition is not well specified in your question, you should get:

```
> table(cut(DS[,1], c(98:101), right=FALSE), cut(DS[,2], c(10:13), right=TRUE))

            (10,11] (11,12] (12,13]
  [98,99)         1       0       0
  [99,100)        0       1       0
  [100,101)       1       1       0
```

Or this:

```
> table(cut(DS[,1], c(98:101), right=FALSE), cut(DS[,2], c(10:13), right=FALSE))

            [10,11) [11,12) [12,13)
  [98,99)         0       1       0
  [99,100)        0       0       1
  [100,101)       2       0       1
```

But not the one you show in OP.